# Icons in Preference Fragment not adapting to night mode

Tags: android, android-preferences, preferencefragment, android-dark-theme

I'm wirting a android app and wanted to make a SettingsActivity.
The problem I have that my vector drawable won't adapt it's color to night or day theme.

ic_palette_black_24dp.xml:

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:tint="#FFFFFF"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path android:fillColor="@color/icon_color_on_surface" android:pathData="M12,3c-4.97,0 -9,4.03 -9,9s4.03,9 9,9c0.83,0 1.5,-0.67 1.5,-1.5 0,-0.39 -0.15,-0.74 -0.39,-1.01 -0.23,-0.26 -0.38,-0.61 -0.38,-0.99 0,-0.83 0.67,-1.5 1.5,-1.5L16,16c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5 0,-4.42 -4.03,-8 -9,-8zM6.5,12c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S5.67,9 6.5,9 8,9.67 8,10.5 7.33,12 6.5,12zM9.5,8C8.67,8 8,7.33 8,6.5S8.67,5 9.5,5s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5S10.33,8 9.5,8zM14.5,8c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S13.67,5 14.5,5s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5S15.33,8 14.5,8zM17.5,12c-0.83,0 -1.5,-0.67 -1.5,-1.5S16.67,9 17.5,9s1.5,0.67 1.5,1.5 -0.67,1.5 -1.5,1.5z"/>
</vector>
```

values/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<resources>
    <color name="icon_color_on_surface">#000000</color>
</resources>
```

values-night/colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="icon_color_on_surface">#FFFFFF</color>
</resources>
```

And in my root_preferences.xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root_preferences">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/title_preference_design">

        <ListPreference
            android:entries="@array/preference_list_theme"
            android:entryValues="@array/preference_list_theme_values"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_palette_black_24dp"
            android:key="list_preference_theme"
            android:tint="@color/icon_color_on_surface"
            android:tintMode="src_atop"
            android:title="@string/preference_category_theme"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_palette_black_24dp" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

[Edit]

Here also my SettingsActivity.java that is basicly the default by AndroidStudio:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegate;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.preference.ListPreference;
import androidx.preference.Preference;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat;
import androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ColorHelper colorHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.settings, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
            // Indicate here the XML resource you created above that holds the preferences
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        }
    }
}
```

[/EDIT]

As you can see in *root_preferences.xml* I already tried setting it by `android:tint=""` and `android:tintMode=""` but no matter what I do the icon color stayes white.
In other Activities the workaround with `android:tint=""` does work.

I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The way to go about this is to define a resource attribute to the `fillColor`. Also, if I recall correctly, the `tint` that you have defined in your vector's XML is either overriding or has no effect on SVG drawables. My drawables don't have the `tint` color set, and the `fillColor` property is dynamic for all drawables.

Below, `android:fillColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary"` is defined by Android System and is already handled by `Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight`. You can also create your own attr values.

```xml
<vector 
    android:height="24dp" 
    android:viewportHeight="24.0" 
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <path 
         android:fillColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" 
         android:pathData="..."
    />
</vector>
```

Depending on your use case, you can also use `textColorPrimary`, `textColorTertiary` from `?android:attr` for different shades.

Comment: What is interesting is, that I have a navigation drawer and I use a white icon there, and everything is handled automatically. If I use the same icon in preference screen , which also understands day night, the icon is not changed but stays it's original color.